# get user ip in validateloginattempt

Tags: meteor

How to get user ip in

`Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function (attempt) {
   console.log(attempt)
});`

I can only see this

[image]

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connection.clientAddress` gives you client ip as a string value. In fact you see that on your screenshot

Comment: as it is a localhost I thought it is not original address, Can you confirm that is exactly the visiting users ip address in production?

Comment: @noName it is. But you should not be aware of dynamic IP addresses and such stuff.